# I want to display all related posts for a selected tag in WordPress

Tags: templates, taxonomy, archive-template

I want to display all the related posts for a selected tag, my purpose is I display all the tag at my posts, if someone clicks on the tag, then it should be re-direct to my tag template `tag.php`. But I am unable to display all the posts related to the tag (which i have clicked at post). my tag

```
<div class="single_detail">
<div class="single_text">
<?php 
//GET THE TAG NAME FORM THE QUIRED OBJECT
$term = get_queried_object();
$tag_name = $term->name;
$args=array('posts_per_page'=>5, 'tag' => $tag_name);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $wp_query->have_posts()) :  
    while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>
<div class="blog_box">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <span class="blog_author">By  <strong><?php echo get_the_author(); ?></strong>  Posted  <strong><?php the_time('F j, Y') ?></strong></span>
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <p><?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,100); ?></p>
    <span class="read_more">Read more</span>
    </a>
</div>
<?php  endwhile; 
    endif;
    ?>
</div> <!-- end of posts details -->
```

How can I get all the post of my selected tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're limiting your query via `posts_per_page` to five results, to get all possible results use `-1`. Don't use `$wp_query` as variable name, as it is associated to a `global` variable with the same name, which can lead to interferences. But that said, you *absolutely don't need a custom query in your `tag.php`*. You are already querying for a specific tag, with `?tag=abc` or `/tag/abc` in your URL. WordPress catches that and selects the correct template, and limits the query to that tag. There is a hierarchy on how [tag template (codex page; read it for more information)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Tag_Templates) files get selected:

1. tag-slug.php
2. tag-id.php
3. tag.php
4. archive.php
5. index.php

If available then the order is first to fifth, if not WordPress is looking for the next one. Additionally I would recommend to give the [Theme Developer Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/) a good read, especially the section about [Template Files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/). In the end you just need a template file to fit your needs. Below a exemplary template file.

```
<?php 
/**
 * The template for displaying tag pages.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Theme
 */ 
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- tag | start -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <?php the_archive_title( '<div class="page-header"><h1 class="page-title">', '</h1></div>' ); ?>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php $description = get_the_archive_description(); ?>
    <?php if ( ! empty( $description ) ) :?>
    <div class="archive-description">
      <?php echo $description; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <!-- tag loop | start -->
    <div id="content" <?php post_class(); ?>>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <?php the_title( '<div class="post-header"><h2 class="post-title">', '</h2></div>' ); ?>
          <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
          <div class="entry-thumbnail">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
          </div><!-- .entry-thumbnail -->
          <?php endif; ?>
          <div class="entry-content">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
          </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- #content -->
    <!-- tag loop | end -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- tag  | end -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```